# Apache beam on google dataflow: Collecting metrics from within the main method

Tags: apache-beam

I have a batch pipeline which pulls data from a cassandra table and writes into kafka. I would like to get various statistics based on cassandra data . For ex, total no.of records in the cassandra table, no.of records having null value for a column etc. I tried to leverage beam metrics. Though it is showing correct count in the google cloud console after the pipeline has completed execution, I am unable to get it in the main program after pipeline.run() method. It throws unsupported exception. I am using google data flow and bundles the pipeline as flex template. Is there anyway to get this work.

Comment: Are you able to get it working if you do not use templates? With templates, the main program does not actually run locally, but elsewhere.

Comment: I did not try without templates, because in production i will be using templates. With templates, its not possible to get? I am getting unsupported exception from DataFlowTemplateJob class

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the job id, dataflow offers a public API that can be used to query metrics which is used [internally](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.43.0/runners/google-cloud-dataflow-java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/dataflow/DataflowPipelineJob.java#L131) . Easier might be to get these from Stackdriver, see, e.g. [Collecting Application Metrics From Google cloud Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59727389/collecting-application-metrics-from-google-cloud-dataflow)

Comment: Maybe you should also mention [the way to create metrics](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#metrics) that will pop into StackDriver.